# Which interpolation method is the most suitable for DEMs?

Tags: arcmap, open-source-gis, dem, interpolation, accuracy

Which interpolation method is the best suitable for hill/valley areas and normal ground with undulations and rivers? When working with Aster 30mX30m DEMs, which method will give the most realistic elevations? I am trying with different methods and getting different contour distribution and shapes but don't know which will give the most accurate and realistic values.

Comment: May be it will be better to add some information: which soft do you use for interpolation and what choices of interpolation methods do you have?

Comment: Till now I am using ArcGis, Erdas, Envi.etc..with IDW,Kriging,Natural Neighbor,Spline,Trend etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder why do you want to interpolate your DEM? It *is* already gridded!

In case you want to interpolate your DEM to smooth your surface I can recommend the "Multilevel B-Spline Interpolation" tool in SAGA-GIS. I made good experiences with it. You can adjust the smoothing-parameter and therefore control the magnitude of smoothing.

Comment: As you suggested, I will try this also. Till now I am using ArcGis, Erdas, Envi.etc.. In my DEM I have areas with hills/valley and also with few undulations areas with straems and sea area....My observation with different types of interpolation methods gives some reliability to some areas(hills or plain area) not realistic to the entire area with one method.

Comment: Did he mean when projecting the data?